# MongoDB and Geo Query

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I have a collection of documents in which there are two important fields for me: srcCoordinates and dstCoordinates. They look like this:

```
"dstCoordinates" : {
    "latitude" : 46.46647770314815,
    "longitude" : 30.642414093017578
}
```

What type of index I must add, to be able to search for all documents within a radius of a given point? Radius - in meters!

I want to do something like this:

```
db.collection.find({dstCoordinates: {$near:[46.46647770314815, 30.642414093017578], $maxDistance: 1000}})
```

1000 - distance in meters!

**In general, the question is: how do I find all points within 1000 meters, for example?**

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a [`geospatial`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/#index-feature-geospatial) index on the "dstCoordinates" field for the $near queries to work.  An example query to create a [`2d`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2d/) index:

```js
db.collection.ensureIndex({"dstCoordinates":"2d"})
```

After the index is created, your find() query should work fine.

**Note:** For storing location information, array are **preferred** in MongoDB.  That is:

> loc : [ longitude , latitude ]

is preferred over

> loc : { lng : longitude , lat : latitude }

Also, you'll need to store the co-ordinates in **longitude, latitude** order

Comment: I tried, but not working....
`     db.markers.find().pretty();
     { "loc" : [ 30.71125, 46.46967 ], "_id" : "ZtRpWApnchNEkwzug" }
     { "loc" : [ 30.70514, 46.46994 ], "_id" : "st8hQ8pfkv8sarfqD" }
     { "loc" : [ 30.71064, 46.4713 ], "_id" : "rruCnSFuiWu54dKJk" }`
Index:
`{
  "v" : 1,
  "key" : {
   "loc" : "2d"
  },
  "ns" : "meteor.markers",
  "name" : "loc_2d"
 }`

Query:
`db.markers.find({"loc": {$near:[30.70514, 46.4699], $maxDistance: 0.006}}).count();
2`
and
`db.markers.find({"loc": {$near:[30.70514, 46.4699], $maxDistance: 1000}}).count();
3`

Comment: For the code you have posted above, it seems to be working as expected.  What's the issue you are seeing?

Comment: Since you are querying legacy co-ordinate pairs, `$maxDistance` is probably in radians rather than meters.  Check out the [`documentation`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/#op._S_near)

Comment: I have to try this type?
`loc: {
  type: 'Point',
  coordinates: [0,1]
}`

Answer (score 0):

Geo query with latitude, longtitude, radius
- Find place from database

```
var geolocation = new Array(-26.90, 50.70 ); // lng, lat
PlacesAPI.aggregate(
            [
            {"$geoNear":
            {"near": {"type":"Point","coordinates": geolocation },
            "spherical":true,
            "distanceField":"distance",
            "maxDistance": 50000
            }
         },
            { $project : {
                    _id:0,
                    name: "$name",
                    details: "$details",
                    distance: "$distance",
                }
            }
            ],function (err, result) {
console.log(result)
})
```